# Live iPhone stream to laptop

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, windows

I am making a self-driving RC car to drive around a track for a school project. I am going to attach my iPhone camera to the car to film. the car is connected to my laptop which needs the video in order to tell the car where to go. How can I upload the video from my iPhone to my computer while the camera is filming continuously? the computer and iPhone would be connected by a cable at all times.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do, but I do not see an option for a wired option. Please see [EpocCam WiFi Virtual Webcam by Kinoni](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/epoccam-wifi-virtual-webcam/id449133483?mt=8) on the App Store

### OR

Connect your iPhone to one a USB port on a Mac, then launch QuickTime. From there, you can click File > New Movie Recording, from there, you will be given a record button with an arrow beside it. Click the arrow, and under "[iPhone Name]" select your iPhone and start recording.

---

Disclosure: I have no connection with the app whatsoever. It’s just what was found in a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop is a MacBook:

Connect your iPhone to one of your MacBook's USB ports, then launch QuickTime player on your laptop. Click File > New Movie Recording, next to the record button, there should be an arrow. Click it, and under "Camera" select your iPhone. Launch the Camera app on your iPhone, and start recording. You should be able to view your iPhone's camera feed from your laptop.